# mdx parameter that contains two words causing an error

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I require help of the experts again!

I have set up a drop down list to be a parameter of another dataset.

When I choose an item that contains two words, it gives me an error saying

> the syntaxt for "the second word" is incorrect.

So is there any way to wrap the whole param as one single string entry?

This is the query of the dataset which is causing the error.

```sql
SELECT
   NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Matters Count] } 
   ON COLUMNS,
   NON EMPTY { ([Matters].[By Division].[APPLICANT TYPE].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,
   MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 
   ON ROWS 
FROM
   (
      select
         strtoset(@Division)
         on columns 
      from
         [CTTT] 
   )
   CELL PROPERTIES VALUE,
   BACK_COLOR,
   FORE_COLOR,
   FORMATTED_VALUE,
   FORMAT_STRING,
   FONT_NAME,
   FONT_SIZE,
   FONT_FLAGS
```

Thanks a lot in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: I haven't seen errors like this before. Maybe you should try to find exact place of error. Try to write this query step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

(StrToSet("[Dimension].[Hierarchy].["+@Division+"]") ON COLUMNS FROM [CTTT])

Where the Dimension and Hierarchy are the ones from your Division dim (e.g. [Matters].[By Division]). This will be more correct anyway, as if you don't include the dim.hier SSAS tries to find the @Division parameter anywhere in the cube.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
I think your answer is correct but the dataset doesn't get populated for some reason. There is no syntax error and so on. weird.

Comment: It is fairly easy to debug - just take the query and replace the parameter with "the member name you are passing". If you are passing a key, the you should do: (StrToSet("[Dimension].[Hierarchy].&["+@Division+"]") ON COLUMNS FROM [CTTT])